# How to calculate Kullback-leiber divergence of Kernel estimation in R

Tags: r

I used Kernel estimation to get a non parametric probability density function. Then, I want to compare the tails 'distance' between two Kernel distribution of continuous variables, using Kullback-leiber divergence. I have tried the following code:

```
kl_l <- function(x,y) {
    integrand <- function(x,y) {

            f.x <- fitted(density(x, bw="nrd0"))
            f.y <- fitted(density(y, bw="nrd0"))

            return((log(f.x)-log(f.y))*f.x) 
    }
    return(integrate(integrand, lower=-Inf,upper=quantile(density(x,  bw="nrd0"),0.25))$value)
    #the Kullback-leiber equation
}
```

When I run `kl_l(a,b)` for a, b = 19 continuous variables, it returns a warning

```
 Error in density(y, bw = "nrd0") : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

**Is there any way to calculate this?**

(If anyone wants to see the actual equation: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/working-paper/2019/attention-to-the-tails-global-financial-conditions-and-exchange-rate-risks.pdf **page 13**.)

Comment: You could take a look at the `KLD` function in the package [LaplacesDemon](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/LaplacesDemon/versions/16.1.4/topics/KLD)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I want to study only the tails of the distributions, meaning that I need a function that allows me to specify the boundaries of the integral (e.g. integral from the value of the 25th quantile of the distribution to -inf). 

check the equation: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/working-paper/2019/attention-to-the-tails-global-financial-conditions-and-exchange-rate-risks.pdf page 13

Comment: There are other implementations of this divergence available for R, but perhaps you've already checked them out. In the code above, I think the problem is that `integrate` works with functions of 1-variable, or at least functions where the integration is on the 1st variable but the second variable takes a constant value. You're not passing the `y` argument in any case.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I think you just need to move the `f.x` and `f.y` outside the integrand (and possibly replace `fitted` with `approxfun`):

```
kl_l <- function(x, y) {
    f.x <- approxfun(density(x, bw = "nrd0"))
    f.y <- approxfun(density(y, bw = "nrd0"))
    integrand <- function(z) {
        return((log(f.x(z)) - log(f.y(z))) * f.x(z)) 
    }
    return(integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = quantile(density(x, bw="nrd0"), 0.25))$value)
    #the Kullback-leiber equation
}
```

Expanding a little:

Looking at the paper you referenced, it appears as though you need to first create the two fitted distributions `f` and `g`. So if your variable `a` contains observations under the 1-standard-deviation increase in global financial conditions, and `b` contains the observations under average global financial conditions, you can create two functions as in your example:

```
f <- approxfun(density(a))
g <- approxfun(density(b))
```

Then define the integrand:

```
integrand <- function(x) log(f(x) / g(x)) * f(x)
```

The upper bound:

```
upper <- quantile(density(b, bw = "nrd0"), 0.25)
```

And finally do the integration on `x` within the specified bounds. Note that each value of `x` in the numerical computation has to go into both `f` and `g`; in your function `kl_l`, the x and y were separately going into the integrand, which I think is incorrect; and in any case, `integrate` will only have operated on the first variable.

```
integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = upper)$value
```

One thing to check for is that `approxfun` returns `NA` for values outside the range specified in the density, which can mess up your operation, so you'll need to adjust for those (if you expect the density to go to zero, for example).